# Webpack missing module error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I recently deleted my node_modules folder from my react app and ran npm install with the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "test",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build webpack -p",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "babel-core": "6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.2",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dashboard": "0.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
  }
}
```

After doing so, I now run into the following console error after running npm start:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (source-map-generator.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (source-map-generator.js:8)
    at Object../node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/source-map-generator.js (source-map-generator.js:399)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap bf59d56b93d65ff61848:669)
    at fn (bootstrap bf59d56b93d65ff61848:87)
    at Object../node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map.js (source-map.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap bf59d56b93d65ff61848:669)
    at fn (bootstrap bf59d56b93d65ff61848:87)
    at Object../node_modules/react-error-overlay/lib/utils/getSourceMap.js (getSourceMap.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap bf59d56b93d65ff61848:669)
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import { PrivateRoute } from './utilities/PrivateRoute'; 
import Home from './components/screens/Home/Home';
import Dashboard from './components/containers/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Menu from './components/containers/Menu/Menu';
import Login from './components/screens/Login/Login';
import Registration from './components/screens/Registration/Registration';
import NoMatch from './components/screens/NoMatch/NoMatch';
import './styles/main.css';
import logo from './assets/img/logo/logo.svg';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="flex-container">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/registration" component={Registration}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/menu" component={Menu}/>
          <Route component={NoMatch}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path              = require('path');
const webpack           = require('webpack');
const htmlPlugin        = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const openBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin'); 
const dashboardPlugin   = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const autoprefixer      = require('autoprefixer'); 

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  images:path.join(__dirname,'src/assets/'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
};

const options = {
  host:'localhost',
  port:'1234'
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.join(PATHS.app,'index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
  },
  devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
      host: options.host,
      port: options.port 
    },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,        
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      },      
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    new dashboardPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
        multiStep: true
    }),
    new htmlPlugin({
      template:path.join(PATHS.app,'index.html'),
      inject:'body'
    }),
    new openBrowserPlugin({
      url: `http://${options.host}:${options.port}`
    })
  ]
};
```

Here are my current environment settings:

- npm version 5.5.1
- node version 7.3.0
- Windows 10

Does anyone have any sort of idea what might be the issue? Looking around it seems that the latest version of react-scripts (1.0.14) has a fix, but I am running that after npm install.

Comment: Your npm version is rather old, can you update to the latest version and try again? `npm i -g npm@latest`

Comment: Good call. I updated and edited. My npm version is now 5.5.1. Unfortunately, the issue still persists.

Comment: I also nuked my node_modules folder and npm installed again to no success :(

Comment: Alright. Since you’ve updated and the issue persist, we will need to see your webpack.config.js file and perhaps the app.js file as well.

Comment: I don't have a webpack.config.js in my solution at this time - is it necessary?

Comment: I had the similar problem before and resolved it by installing an older version of `npm` (`npm install -g npm@5.0.3`).

Comment: @SeanLee webpack.config.js is needed to make those module imports work, as well as transpile your es6+ code to es5. Try adding a sample webpack config and specify webpack task in your build task in package.json

Comment: We need that to see if there are any configuration that was set incorrectly.

Comment: Gotcha, looks like adding in the webpack.config.js properly fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know, but it looks like you have error in your code, you try to import switch and route from wrong package. React-router - 3 version, and react-router-dom - 4 version, so your code should look like below;

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```